# Adding vue.js vm to mvc layout pag, getting Vue not valid constructor error

Tags: vue.js

Trying to create a vue instance binding to an MVC layout page.  Getting a Vue is not a valid constructor error.

Inside app.js :

```
var clock = new Vue({
el:'#clock',
data: {
    time:'',
    date:''
}
});

var week = ['SUN', 'MON', 'TUE', 'WED', 'THU', 'FRI', 'SAT'];
var timerID = setInterval(updateTime, 1000);

function updateTime() {
    var cd = new Date();
    clock.time = zeroPadding(cd.getHours(), 2) + ':' + zeroPadding(cd.getMinutes(), 2) + ':' + zeroPadding(cd.getSeconds(), 2);
    clock.date = zeroPadding(cd.getFullYear(), 4) + '-' + zeroPadding(cd.getMonth()+1, 2) + '-' + zeroPadding(cd.getDate(), 2) + ' ' + week[cd.getDay()];
};

function zeroPadding(num, digit) {
  var zero = '';
  for(var i = 0; i < digit; i++) {
    zero += '0';
}
return (zero + num).slice(-digit);
}


Vue.createApp(clock.app().mount('#clock'));
```

_Layout.cshtml :

[image: layout references]

[image]

[image]

Getting the vue is not a valid constructor error.  Not sure how to fix this. Thanks

Comment: it looks like you're using vue 3

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim how would I implement this using the correct version of Vue?